# Updating variables in a list using python's csv module

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

Here's what I have:

```
import csv

a=8   
print a    
mylist = [a,'2','3']    
myfile = open("myfile.csv", "wb") # csv files should always be opened in binary mode 
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)    
wr.writerow(mylist)    
a = a + 1    
print a    
wr.writerow(mylist)
```

The result of the prints are `8` and `9`, just as I would expect.  When I open the file I created I have the result:

```
"8","2","3"     
"8","2","3"
```

The top row is what I would expect, but the second row starts with `"8"` rather than `"9"`.  I understand I can work around this by inserting `mylist = [a,'2','3']` again after I redefine the variable, but would someone mind explaining to me why I have to reinsert the list line or why the variable isn't automatically updated in the list?  Is there another approach I can use to avoid having to reinsert the list line each time I want to update a variable?

Comment: @Tichodroma - I believe you edited my post to improve the formatting.  Thank you for doing so.  May I ask where I should go for formatting guidelines so that my work doesn't need to be cleaned in the future?

Comment: Sure, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the line:

```
a = a + 1
```

in which you reassigned `a` to a new integer, which is not connected to its previous value.

Anyway, integers are immutable variables and you cannot do anything else with it than reassign.

As @thg435 comments, list operation `some_list = some_list + [5]` would have the same effect. However, lists are mutable objects and you can use `some_list.append(5)`, which would modify the list and reflect its changes into the csv file.

If you work with mutable objects (list, dict), you can modify their values:

```
import csv
a=8   
mylist = [a,'2','3']    
with open("myfile.csv", "wb") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)    
    wr.writerow(mylist)    
    mylist[0] = mylist[0] + 1  ####  here you modify a list
    wr.writerow(mylist)
```

Comment: Immutability is irrelevant here. `some_list = some_list + [5]` would have exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
a = 1
mylist = [a,2,3]
print mylist # [1,2,3]
```

`mylist` is a structure with three elements, first of which points to the variable `a` which has the value `1`

```
----------       -------------
| mylist | --->  |   |  2|  3|
----------       -------------
                   |
                   v   
                 -----      -----
                 | a | ---> | 1 |
                 -----      -----
```

Now let's change `a`:

```
   a = a + 1
   print mylist # still [1,2,3]
```

We've created a **new** variable and gave it the name `a`, thus revoking that name from the first variable.The first element of the list still points to the first (now unnamed) variable. These two variables are not related in any way.

```
----------       -------------
| mylist | --->  |   |  2|  3|
----------       -------------
                   |
                   v   
                 -----      -----
                 | ? | ---> | 1 |
                 -----      -----

-----      -----
| a | ---> | 2 |
-----      -----
```